# Count the number of sequences that $|a_i - a_{i + 1}| \leq K \forall i = 1, 2, …, n - 1 $.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion, dynamic-programming

A sequence $a_1, a_2, …, a_n$ called superseq length n if:

$a_1 = 0$

$a_n = H$

$|a_i - a_{i + 1}|≤K∀i = 1, 2, …, n - 1$

$0≤a_i≤H∀i = 1, 2, …, n$

Given $n, H, K (K \leq H)$ count the number of superseq length $n$

How to find the recursion formula of this problem? And which variable we use for that formula?

I think it is $n$
If $n=2$, $S_n = 1, 2$ if $K=H$ or not

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to let $H$ vary?

Comment: @Yorch, $S(n, h) = S(n-1, h) + S(n-1, h-1) + ... + S(n-1, h-k)$. I think this false because $k$ is given.

Comment: I think the correct one is $S(n,h) = S(n-1,h-1) + \dots + S(n-1,h-k)$, for $n\geq k+1$.

Comment: Suppose $K=H$, how to Calculate $S(n, H)$ ?

Comment: if $K=H$ wouldn't the answer be $\binom{H-2}{n-2}$ ?

Comment: How about $0≤a_i≤H∀i = 1, 2, …, n$?